# Using GTK4 to build a small window app

Tags: gcc, gtk, executable, binary

Once the small program is compiled, I run it by double clicking the executable in Nautilus.  When I have a second but completely different windowed app and double click on it while the first windowed program is running, the result is that the first program is started for a second instance rather than a new instance of the different program.

Program 1:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

//gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o example-0 example-0.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 ) -lGL -g

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

    printf("EXITING\n");
  return status;
}
```

Program 2:

```
//gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o example-1 example-1.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 ) 
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
  gtk_widget_set_halign (box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_valign (box, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);

  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), box);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");

  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_destroy), window);

  gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box), button);

  gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

I cannot figure out why.  Has anybody else ever ran across this problem?  I should be easily reproducible.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
I have GTK v4 and the following compiler version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
```

also using Wayland.

Thanks,
Jaye

Comment: Have you tested with straight X and not Wayland?  It might be a Wayland related issue as Wayland introduces issues with some GUI applications (unfortunately).  Just to rule out Wayland as the source of the problem/

Comment: Yes I have.  I have determined the problem is with the activate signal in GTK4.  I have opened a ticket on gnome gitlab.  Thanks though for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Two different GTK applications should have two different `application_id`. For example `org.gtk.example1` and `org.gtk.example2` in the `gtk_application_new()` instruction.

See https://docs.gtk.org/gio/type_func.Application.id_is_valid.html

Comment: In the original question it was answered and dealt with in the comments. I fail to see how this is an answer.

Comment: I have tested your two examples and have the same problem (Kubuntu 22.10): trying to launch example-1 is launching example-0 a second time if example-0 is already running. Just use two different id strings in app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); and the problem is fixed.